# Using Qt 5.8, can I send & receive beacons on android & iOS devices?

Tags: qt, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon, qt5.8

I want to use my Qt app based on `Qt5.8` to be able to send & receive beacons in iBeacon format.

When I run the heart-rate listener example in `Qt5.8` on `iOS`, it is able scan some nearby beacon devices & connect. But, I need an example of sending data back & forth.

**Is beacons based communication (send+receive) on `Qt 5.8` fully supported on `android` & `iOS` ?**

Comment: The log line suggests advertising (send) is not supported in Qt for Android.

Comment: @davidgyoung I have edited the question now. That is limitation only to run the server app. But in a simple way - All I need is a basic example of sending & receiving some numbers as beacons using Qt & BLE